# Plotly: How to plot specific rows on Bubble Map?

Tags: python, plotly, bubble-chart

How can I plot certain state's magnitude on a Bubble Map using Plotly for Python? (ie: plot west and east coast states only)

I've looked at Plotly's examples, but not much explanation is given on how to reproduce same plot (https://plotly.com/python/bubble-maps/#united-states-bubble-map)

Sample data:

```
             state  latitude   longitude  mag
0          Alabama   34.7360  -85.629000  4.8
1           Alaska   71.1404 -131.232000  7.9
2          Arizona   36.9940 -109.058700  5.3
3         Arkansas   36.4400  -89.920000  5.0
4       California   41.9780 -115.366000  7.3
```

My code:

```
every_earthquake = pd.read_csv('earthquake_states.csv')

fifty_state_quakes = every_earthquake[['state', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'mag']].dropna()
state_mag_max = pd.DataFrame(fifty_state_quakes, columns=['state', 
                        'latitude', 'longitude', 'mag']).dropna()
state_max_mag_df = state_mag_max.groupby(['state'])['latitude', 'longitude','mag'].max().reset_index()

state_max_mag_df['text'] = state_max_mag_df['state'] + '<br>Magnitude ' + (state_max_mag_df['mag']).astype(str)
magnitude = [(0,1), (2,3), (4,5), (5,6), (7,8), (9, 10)]
colors = ['royalblue','crimson','lightseagreen','orange','lightgrey']
scale = 0.45

fig = go.Figure()

for i in range(len(magnitude)):
    magn = magnitude[i]
    state_max_mag_df1 = state_max_mag_df[(state_max_mag_df['mag'] >= magn[0]) & (state_max_mag_df['mag'] < magn[1])]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
    locationmode = 'USA-states',
    lon = state_max_mag_df['latitude'],
    lat = state_max_mag_df['latitude'],
    text = state_max_mag_df['text'],
    marker = dict(
        size = state_max_mag_df['mag']/scale,
        color = colors,
        line_color = 'rgb(40,40,40)',
        line_width = 0.5,
        sizemode = 'area'),
    name = '{0} - {1}'.format(magn[0], magn[1])))

      fig.update_layout(
      showlegend = True,
      geo = dict(scope = 'usa',
              landcolor = 'rgb(217, 217, 217)',
              ))
    fig.show()
```

Output I'm getting:

[image: West East Coast Magnitudes]

Output I would like to achieve with West and East State Magnitudes:
[image: West Coast Magnitudes]

Comment: There seems to be a small bug in your code as you are passing the same value to Plotly for both latitude and longitude, as in the code above you have written `lon = state_max_mag_df['latitude']` and
`lat = state_max_mag_df['latitude']`.

Comment: According to Plotly's example, I have to take the latitude and longitude column from the data set created using CSV to find the exact coordinates of state's earthquake, correct? How can I identify coordinates and plot accordingly?

Comment: You have both latitude and longitude in your data frame, but you are not using the longitude, you are using the latitude twice as you are setting `lon = state_max_mag_df['latitude']` and also `lat = state_max_mag_df['latitude']`.

Comment: Wow, I apologize for my stupidity. I overlooked that. I've added 'longitude' now, but seems other state magnitudes don't align on the bubble map. Should I change the scale or line width?

Comment: No worries :) If you can share a link to your CSV file I will take a look.

Comment: I obtained the CSV from here: https://github.com/BuzzFeedNews/2015-03-earthquake-maps/blob/master/data/earthquake_states.csv
I'd greatly appreciate it and would like to give you credit or +1 for your help. Thank you

Comment: I posted the updated code below. There was another issue as you were defining a separate data frame `state_max_mag_df1` for each magnitude range inside the loop, but you were not using this data frame in the plot. The plot was still using `state_max_mag_df`.

Comment: Ah! Okay. I should keep the renaming of data more simple next time and look more carefully at which data is being used. Thank you. I appreciate it. The code you have provided, the bubble plots for specific state are in the wrong states, is: California is in Nevada. How can display the bubble plots for California in the California state boundary and Alaska showing bubble plots in Alaska and not Hawaii?

Comment: The problem comes from this line of code `state_max_mag_df = state_mag_max.groupby(['state'])['latitude', 'longitude','mag'].max().reset_index()` which takes the maximum latitude and longitude separately from each state. This is why the bubbles are not where they should be.

Comment: I see. In order for the max magnitude for each state and correspondingly latitude/longitude, I'd have to remove it from that line of code. I used that code because I thought if I didn't display longitude/latitude the plotly graph may not use that data. I learned a lot from your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

every_earthquake = pd.read_csv('earthquake_states.csv')
fifty_state_quakes = every_earthquake[['state', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'mag']].dropna()
state_mag_max = pd.DataFrame(fifty_state_quakes, columns=['state', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'mag']).dropna()
state_max_mag_df = state_mag_max.groupby(['state'])['latitude', 'longitude','mag'].max().reset_index()
state_max_mag_df['text'] = state_max_mag_df['state'] + '<br>Magnitude ' + (state_max_mag_df['mag']).astype(str)
magnitude = [(0,1), (2,3), (4,5), (5,6), (7,8), (9, 10)]
colors = ['#E58606', '#5D69B1', '#52BCA3', '#99C945', '#CC61B0', '#24796C']
scale = 5

fig = go.Figure()

for i in range(len(magnitude)):

    magn = magnitude[i]

    state_max_mag_df1 = state_max_mag_df[(state_max_mag_df['mag'] >= magn[0]) & (state_max_mag_df['mag'] < magn[1])]

    fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
    locationmode = 'USA-states',
    lon = state_max_mag_df1['longitude'],
    lat = state_max_mag_df1['latitude'],
    text = state_max_mag_df1['text'],
    marker = dict(
        size = state_max_mag_df1['mag'] * scale,
        color = colors[i],
        line_color = 'rgb(40,40,40)',
        line_width = 0.5,
        sizemode = 'diameter'),
    name = '{0} - {1}'.format(magn[0], magn[1])))

fig.update_layout(
  showlegend = True,
  geo = dict(scope = 'usa', landcolor = 'rgb(217, 217, 217)')
)

fig.show()
```